# How to evaluate a sum which contains limit variables?

Tags: limits, summation, rationality-testing

> How to evaluate a sum which contains limit variables?

For example: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n-1}n\frac{1+i(n-1)}n $$

And would the result necessarily be rational, because each term appears to be the multiplication of two rational fractions?

Comment: For fixed $n$, your reasoning shows it is rational.  But the limit in $n$ of rationals need not be rational.

Comment: Are you saying that a sum of infinitely many rational terms need not be rational?

Comment: Precisely.  Any *finite* sum of rational terms will indeed be rational, however once it becomes an infinite sum there is no longer any guarantee.  Take for example $e = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how that's possible! If that's a sum of rational fractions, how could it possibly equal an irrational? It seems to defy the definition of rational numbers, as I would assume all terms could achieve a common denominator and be summed.

Comment: @Danny This comes from the fact that the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, denoted by $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$.  Read further on the subject at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28topology%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point  Again, had the summation been a finite summation, it would indeed have been rational, however since it is an infinite sum, it could be any limit point of a sequence of rationals, which includes all real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in the sum, each piece has a common factor of $\frac{n-1}{n^2}$ which can be pulled out of the sum as per the distributive property since it does not depend on the index, $i$.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1+i(n-1)}{n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1+i(n-1)\right)\right)$$

Now, what is remains in the sum can be split into two seperate sums with the one on the right again having a common factor of $(n-1)$ present which can be brought outside.

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1\right)+\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni\right)\right)$$

The left sum is equal to $n$ since there are $n$ occurences of adding $1$ together, and the right sum is the $n$th triangle number, given by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n^2}(n)+\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\right)$$

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: What about if you can't pull n out of the sums themselves?

Comment: I used the property that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (\alpha\cdot f(i))=\alpha\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^k f(i)$.  If there is a stranger more complicated way in which $n$ is being used, such as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^n$, then a different argument would need to be used, perhaps for example using a form of the cauchy-schwarz inequality.  It would certainly be more difficult to obtain an exact answer unless it happened to diverge or converge to a simple quantity.

Comment: And is this necessarily rational as n approaches $\infty$?

Comment: The punchline at the end of all of this, is that the limit of the above quantity diverges to infinity as it is $\mathscr{O}(n^2)$ and $\infty$ is not defined to be rational or irrational as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
S_n &= \frac{n-1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n} n + \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\\
&= \frac{n-1}{n}\left( 1 + \frac{n^2-1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
This seems to go towards $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to evaluating such limits of sums is as follows. Say we are considering
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{f(n)}g(n)\approx \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{f(n)}g(x)\ dx.
$$
For any reasonable functions $f$ and $g$, you can make the $\approx$ rigorous by using Riemann sums for the integral. Then we use something called the characteristic function:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{f(n)}g(x)\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,f(n)]}g(x)\ dx.
$$
Say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$. Then we can pass the limit inside the integral to obtain
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{f(n)}g(n)\approx \int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,L]}g(x)\ dx.
$$
Note that there are some more hypotheses on $g$ necessary in order to pass the limit inside. The resulting integral can be computed using integration by parts if necessary (for instance, if there isn't a closed form antiderivative for $g(x)$).

If you have other specific examples, I could provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I actually translated ln(n) into the integral from 1 to n of (1/x)dx into this Riemann sum in order to try to solve a problem.

Comment: Don't do that! If you start off with a continuous expression, its much easier to compute than its discrete approximation... what was your original problem?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the Euler-Mascheroni constant hasn't been proved rational or irrational, and I was thinking that maybe if I could show that ln(n) was rational for any given n then the entire constant must be rational. Of course now I'm seeing that it's infinite so neither rational or irrational.

Comment: Yeah this idea won't work, because you would get $\infty-\infty$ for the Euler-Mascheroni constant. The main way of proving that a number is irrational is to bound its distance away from any rational number: see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~khlee/math2784s10/piande.pdf

Comment: The issue is that the formulas for approximations for the Eurler-Mascheroni constant are much more complicated than those for e, so no one has been able to get through all the calculations successfully.

Comment: Hm this looks like a good idea. What I don't understand now though is why the Euler-Mascheroni constant has the value it has! If the limit of the second term, ln(n), turns out to be infinity, and if the first term is a rational sum, then shouldn't the constant be equal to a rational sum - infinity = negative infinity?